# indexes needed for table inheritance in postgres?

Tags: postgresql, inheritance, indexing, unique

This is a fairly simple question, but it's one I can't find a firm answer on.

I have a parent table in PostgreSQL, and then several child tables which have been defined.  A trigger has been established, and the children tables only have data inserted if a field, say field *x*, meets a certain criteria.

When I query the parent table with a field based upon *x*, PostgreSQL knows to immediately go to the child table that is related to that particular value of *x*.

That all being said, I don't need to specify a particular index on the column *x* do I?  PostgreSQL already knows how to sort on it, and by adding an index to the parent *x*, PostgreSQL is therefore generating unique indexes on *x* for each of the new child tables.

Creating that index is a bit redundant, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Creating an index on the child table for x, if x only has one value (or a very, very small number of values) if probably a loss, yes.  The planner would scan the whole table anyway.

If x is a timestamp and you're specifying a timeframe that may not be a whole partition, or if x is another range or set of values, an index would be a win most likely.

Edit: When I say one value or range of values, I mean, per child table.

Comment: x is a site name that is a predefined list.  so, for example, the parent table may be 'city_description', with column 'city'.  say i have 10 children tables, 'chicago_city_description', 'dallas_city_description', 'nyc_city_description'..., where my trigger makes the decision for the child table based upon the value of 'city'.  this column will never be a timestamp.  so getting rid of the index is fine?

Comment: If x is a site name and there is one site name per child table - get rid of the index.